# How prove this integral always is constant?

Tags: analysis

> let $u(x,y)\in C^2(\mathcal D)$,where $D= \Bbb R^2$,and such
>   $$\Delta u=0,(x,y)\in \mathcal D$$
>   and 
>   $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x+2\pi,y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,y),\forall x\in R$$

show that
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]dx=\text{Constant}$$

maybe we can use [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem),but I can't How to deal this term $\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2$

Comment: $D=R^2$ mean $D=\mathbb R^2$ ? Wouldn't it be more $D\subset \mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: Yes,It's mean $D=R^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $$F(y)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]dx=\text{Constant}$$ is equivalent to show $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0.$$
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}-2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right]dx.$$
As $\Delta u=0$,

\begin{eqnarray}
F(y)&=&2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\right]dx\\
&=&2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]dx\\
&=&2\left[\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]^{2\pi}_{x=0}\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}